# Авторизация в Instagram 2016

Tags: c#, instagram

Как залогиниться в инстаграм при текущих реалиях? Делаю так:

```
// готовим поля для формы входа
var fields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
fields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username));
fields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password));

// готовим запрос
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/accounts/login/ajax/");
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(fields);

request.Headers.Referrer = new Uri(m_client.BaseAddress, "/accounts/login/");

// Дополнительные заголовки запроса.
// Кроме X-CSRFToken, остальное в общем-то не обязательно.
request.Headers.Add("origin", m_client.BaseAddress.ToString());
request.Headers.Add("x-csrftoken", csrftoken);
request.Headers.Add("x-instagram-ajax", "1");
request.Headers.Add("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");

// Авторзуемся через AJAX
// var response = await m_client.PostAsync("/accounts/login/", new FormUrlEncodedContent(fields));
// var response = await m_client.SendAsync(request);
// var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginInfo>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

// Авторзуемся через AJAX
using (var response = await m_client.SendAsync(request))
{
    var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginInfo>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    return info.authenticated;
}
```

Получаю ошибку 405. Кстати, раньше тот же код работал. Добавили дополнительную проверку?

Comment: тоже интересен этот вопрос

Comment: Неплохо было бы уточнить контекст. Куда уходит ваш запрос, на какой конечный `Uri`? Вообще, дайте код подготовки `m_client`.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, уже не актуально, но [Istagram внёс изменения в политику работы с API 1 июня](https://www.searchengines.ru/instagram_zakry.html).

> Фотосервис Instagram внёс изменения в политику работы с API. Это
>   привело к прекращению работы сторонних сервисов, которые позволяли
>   просматривать ленты друзей пользователя.
>
> Instagram также закроет доступ к API тем приложениям, которые
>   позволяют автоматически подписываться на пользователей, отмечать их
>   фотографии как понравившиеся и оставлять под ними комментарии.
>
> С 1 июня Instagram позволяет подключаться к своим API только
>   приложениям для редактирования фотографий, а также аналитическим и
>   маркетинговым сервисам.

[Оригинал новости на сайте Instagram](http://developers.instagram.com/post/145262544121/instagram-platform-update-effective-june-1-2016)

Comment: Вопрос очевидно не про работу с API.

Comment: @ilyapt вопрос был, не добавили ли доп.проверку. А т.к. раньше этот же код работал, то я предположил, что дело как раз в изменении политики работы с Instagram